# Read EPPlus DataTable in Excel from specific colums

Tags: c#, excel, razor, datatable, epplus

Hi Im new to using EPPlus Excel Uploader and Datatable, My question is, is it possible to finish the rows from Male (A-D column) after proceeding to the Female Rows (E-H) ? 
Sorry in Advance because I cant find any code or how to ask this question that can solve my problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all the rows of the Males and then the Females.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    //set the column start positions for both sexes
    int startMale = 1;
    int startFemale = 5;

    //first the males. start at row 2 to skip the header
    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
    {
        string FirstName = worksheet.Cells[row, startMale].Value.ToString();
        string LastName = worksheet.Cells[row, startMale + 1].Value.ToString();
        string Sex = worksheet.Cells[row, startMale + 2].Value.ToString();
        string Age = worksheet.Cells[row, startMale + 3].Value.ToString();
    }

    //then the females
    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
    {
        string FirstName = worksheet.Cells[row, startFemale].Value.ToString();
        string LastName = worksheet.Cells[row, startFemale + 1].Value.ToString();
        string Sex = worksheet.Cells[row, startFemale + 2].Value.ToString();
        string Age = worksheet.Cells[row, startFemale + 3].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```